# Calling 'scrollView.zoom' Does Not Zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

For some reason scrollView.zoom does not zoom in on an imageView.

I have an imageView inside a scrollView.

in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
        scrollView.delegate = self
```

viewForZooming:

```swift
   func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {            
        return imageView
    }
```

Now, I'm calling below after both scrollView and imageView are initialized.

```swift
var scale: CGFloat = 2

let location = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width/2, y: imageView.frame.height/2)
scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale, center: location), animated: true)
```

Nothing is happening after `scrollView.zoom` is called. I tried doing

```swift
view.setNeedsDisplay()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Still nothing happens, imageView is not zooming in.

UPDATE:

As requested, here is the code for scrollView and imageView initialization:

```swift
func createscrollView(image: UIImage?){

    if image == nil{
        let img = UIImage(named: "demo image.jpg")
        let imgCorrected = scaleAndOrient(image: img!)

        //created user selecged images
        userSelectedImage_UI = img
        userSelectedImage_UI_Corrected = imgCorrected
    }


    // create image scroll view
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 100, height: 100))
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
    scrollView.bounces = false
    scrollView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -150),
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0)
    ])


    // add image view to scrollview
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: 100, height: 100))
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1)
    ])

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    if image == nil{
        imageView.image = userSelectedImage_UI_Corrected

    } else {
        imageView.image = scaleAndOrient(image: image!)
    }


}
```

Comment: And your imageView is inside your scrollView? Can you post that code?

Comment: updated the question with imageView and scrollView

Comment: @mezzi - what is your `scaleAndOrient()` func doing? Testing your code - without the `scaleAndOrient()` call - and adding a button to call `.zoom(to: ...)`, it seems to work fine.

Comment: scaleAndOrient just scales down input image to lower resolution. The code in my question works if I call it with double tap action or if I call it with button action like you did. It does not work when I call it from another method, without button trigger. If you try calling the method right after both imageView and scrollView are created (after last if else statement in my code), it wont' work. That's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments...

It sounds like you are creating / setting up your scrollView and its content imageView from `viewDidLoad()` and then immediately trying to "zoom" it.

If so, that will be problematic, as auto-layout hasn't finished laying out the UI elements.

You *can* call it from:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var scale: CGFloat = 2
    let location = CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.width/2, y: imageView.frame.height/2)
    scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale, center: location), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It should work in viewDidLoad() as well (it does for me). You may need to call `scrollView.setNeedsLayout()` after creating your scrollView programmatically.

Comment: @elliott-io - yes, you *can* call it from `viewDidLoad()` ... after calling `scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()`, but... it's never a good idea to call methods that rely on layout - ***particularly*** one like this that uses `animated: true` - from `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Definitely agreed! viewDidLoad is not the correct place to zoom. That data wasn't revealed by OP until you guessed it (nice work). Autolayout may still not finish laying out elements if they are created after a view is loaded or at some other dynamic place, and so won't zoom without a layout update. Wanted to make sure OP and others looking for a solution are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem is in your zoomRectForScale function, though it isn't posted. It should be something like this:

```
func zoomRectForScale(_ scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
    var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
    zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height / scale
    zoomRect.size.width = imageView.frame.size.width / scale
    let newCenter = scrollView.convert(center, from: imageView)
    zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
    zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
    return zoomRect
}
```

Additionally, I've verified that double-tapping to zoom works to the correct location using:

```
var gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

// Sets up the gesture recognizer that receives double taps to auto-zoom
func setupGestureRecognizer() {
    gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

// Handles a double tap by either resetting the zoom or zooming to where was tapped
@IBAction func handleDoubleTap() {
    if scrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
        scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view)), animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call this in viewDidLoad:

```
setupGestureRecognizer()
```

If this doesn't solve your issue, please adjust your question with missing code functions and variable declarations.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, yes my zoomRectForScale is identical to yours, and yes when I use it with double-tapping zoom in it works fine as well. However, I need to call it not from double tap button action, but from another method. Basically, once imageView and scrollView are setup and initialized, I need to call zoom in to location var I mentioned earlier, which weirdly does not work.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps there is a problem getting your center point. Does `scrollView.setZoomScale(2, animated: true)` work at all? I understand it's not zooming a specific point, but I just want to make sure it is working.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work either. I feel like something is not triggering the view to update, the way it does when called from double tap action. Because if I put scrollView.setZoomScale(2, animated: true) inside double tap action, it works fine

Comment: You can try `scrollView.setNeedsLayout()` if you're calling your zoom function immediately after creating the scrollView.